# Android TranslateAnimation move view to another view

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I'd like to move my view from first layout to another layout, I use TranslateAnimation but it move my view to wrong place.
How I can get view's coordinates and move my view to them?

code:

```
private void moveViewToNextView(View view,View v2) {
     int originalPos[] = new int[2];
     v2.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);
     TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, originalPos[0],  0, originalPos[1] );
     anim.setDuration(1000);
     anim.setFillAfter(true);
     view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all use Object animator instead of TranslateAnimation , Object animator is only thing that moves object , translateanimation doesnt change its position on screen.

`ObjectAnimator transAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, propertyName, fromX, toX);
transAnimation.setDuration(3000);
transAnimation.start();`

Comment: I do not need to change your real coordinates, only the appearance of